# Access dynamic property of an interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If I have an interface:

```
export interface Person {
  [key: string]: {
    name: string;
    alias: string;
    active: string[];
    values: string[];
  };
}
```

If I want to access:

```
{
  name: string;
  alias: string;
  active: string[];
  values: string[];
};
```

How can I do this? I tried `Person[keyof typeof Person]` but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type X = Person[keyof Person];
```

Will return type:

```
type X = {
  name: string;
  alias: string;
  active: string[];
  values: string[];
}
```

Comment: Damn it! So close, I could swear I tried that!

Comment: you could just replace `keyof Person` with `string`

Comment: Or even `number`, because formally `keyof Person` is `string | number`.